# Get full quality image from camera

Tags: android, image

When I take a picture with the camera and then I want to show this image in a ImageView, I was following the next method:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PHOTO_REQUEST_FRAG);

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST_FRAG:
            if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK && data != null) {

                Bitmap srcBmp = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

                ... (process image to scale size and rotate if necesary)

                pic_view.setImageBitmap(srcBmp);
            }
    }
}
```

I was getting the image and showing it in the ImageView correctly, but I have realized that the image obtained was of very low quality. After some research I found that the image obtained with this method is the thumbnail of the image taken. So I modified the code following some indications from other SO posts talking about this:

```
String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
String imageFilePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "Pictures/timeStamp.jpg";
takenPicUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(imageFilePath));
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, takenPicUri);
startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PHOTO_REQUEST_FRAG);

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST_FRAG:
            if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK && data != null) {

                Bitmap srcBmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getActivity().getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri), null, null);

                ... (process image to scale size and rotate if necesary)

                pic_view.setImageBitmap(srcBmp);
            }
    }
}
```

But now, the image is not being shown in the ImageView(pic_view). In the other posts I have read people report that this method worked for them, but is not working for me. I'm forgetting something or I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: This code will return low quality image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I have read in old posts that this way of doing this could cause trouble because there was some bug related to it but is the only way in that I have achieved to make it work.

Is as simple as this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PHOTO_REQUEST_FRAG);

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST_FRAG:
            if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK && data != null) {

                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                Bitmap srcBmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getActivity().getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri), null, null);

                ... (process image to scale size and rotate if necesary)

                pic_view.setImageBitmap(srcBmp);
            }
    }
}
```

This way is working on android 5.0 and 4.4.4.

Comment: what about devices older than 4.4.4?